# how to use grep to extract the content of a string with multiple (") starting from the first double quote to the second one

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have this string `<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">`

and I'm trying to extract only this `.MainActivity` from that string

I used

```
grep -o -P '(?<=android:name=").*(?=")' output.txt
```

but it extracts `.MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan`

Is there any way to extract only from the first double quote to the next one, not to the last one?

Comment: Apart from the Perl-style non-greedy match, you can use a character class to matching anything but a double-quote: `[^"]`. Advantage: works with most non-Perl regex-engines too. Disadvantage: hard to use with a multi-character separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a non greedy match by adding a "?" after the star.

```
grep -o -P '(?<=android:name=").*?(?=")'
```